# Publishing as an undergraduate student: can/should I list my university affiliation?

Tags: publications

I have done some research during the past year on one of the topics I am studying. Now I have got some nice results which I think I should publish. I think I can write a conference paper based on my results; a journal one might be too difficult at this point.

I have conducted the research alone, and have not received any help from any faculty members. Now, when I'm writing the paper, I came to consider for the first time am I *allowed* to publish under the institution I am studying in? I mean, I can list my university as my affiliation, even though I'm just an undergrad student, right? .. I could not find anything on this from the university rules, so I guess its "quiet information".

Comment: _am I allowed to publish under the institution I am studying in?_ — Of course you are!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ask one of your professors or the administration about what the best course of action is.

Most likely, you should publish as affiliated to the university as the work was conducted while you were at university. In any case, you have nothing to lose by doing so.